# Converting .xls to .shp

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online, excel

I'm very much a GIS novice but have been maintained an interactive tool on arcGIS for several years and am only now experiencing a problem with it. We are collect and update data on an Excel spreadsheet. Up to this point, when we want to make an update on arcGIS, we download the spreadsheet as .xls and use myGeoData.cloud to convert to .shp before uploading the new data.

When trying to make an upload now, I receive an error message that there is no location data in the dataset. We have City, State, Country data on all data points and have never had trouble converting to .shp before. I suppose I could geocode the whole set and get lat/long for everything but am not sure why this conversion process that I've done several times before is no longer working. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you facing an error with converting your excel to SHP using MyGeoData Converter OR facing difficulties adding the excel to ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Please add some sample excel records

Comment: @YogeshChavan, Thank you for the response! I'm having trouble converting from excel to SHP using MyGeoData. I do have tokens to do the conversion on arcGIS but it's been much easier in the past to just upload the SHP directly to arcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

myGeodata.cloud has this note for Excel>Shape conversion:

> **Notice to XLS format** - Detection of columns containing coordinates is based on attribute name - please rename columns containing coordinates to any of these: x, xcoord, xcoordinate, coordx, coordinatex, longitude, long (and of course: y, ycoord, ycoordinate, coordy, coordinatey, latitude, lat). If you have geometry as WKT or WKB, use wkt or wkt name for the geometry column name.

My first suggestion is that you check your Excel file and make sure these conditions are satisfied.